# minimazing function , how to pass arguments into a function scipy

Tags: python, scipy

I've written a code for minimizing a certain function with respect to r and alpha using scipy . However I encountered a problem with passing an argument to a function.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import numpy as np
from scipy.integrate import quad
import scipy.optimize as opt

def integrand(t, alpha, r):
    return np.exp(-alpha*(t-r))**2

def my_function(parameters, rho):
    alpha = parameters[0]
    r = parameters[1]
    return quad(integrand, 0, rho, args=(alpha, r))[0]

alpha_0 = 1
r_0 = 1
rho = 5.0

vec_expint = np.vectorize(my_function)

res = opt.minimize(my_function(rho), np.asarray([alpha_0, r_0]), method='CG', tol=1.e-2, options={'gtol': 0.01, 'maxiter': 5})
print(res)
```

I want to put integration bounds as variables. I added a variable rho and I'm getting the following error message:

```
 res = opt.minimize(my_function(rho), np.asarray([alpha_0, r_0]), method='CG', tol=1.e-2, options={'gtol': 0.01, 'maxiter': 5})
    TypeError: my_function() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)
```

Could anybody explain me how to pass arguments in the right way, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have defined:

```
def my_function(parameters, rho):
```

Now try

```
my_function(1)
```

What's the error?  The obvious Python one, right? When you run

```
 res = opt.minimize(**my_function(rho)**, np.asarray([alpha_0, r_0]), method='CG', tol=1.e-2, options={'gtol': 0.01, 'maxiter': 5})
```

it doesn't even get past that expression I highlighted.

There are a couple of solutions:

- define a new function that takes just one parameter, `parameters`, and defines `rho` before hand.  That can be done with a `def`, a `lambda` or `partial`.
- give `optimize` an `args` parameter. You are already using the `args` feature when calling `quad`.

Answer (score 1):

use `args` parameter.

My Code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import numpy as np
from scipy.integrate import quad
import scipy.optimize as opt

def integrand(t, alpha, r):
    return np.exp(-alpha*(t-r))**2

def my_function(parameters, rho):
    alpha = parameters[0]
    r = parameters[1]
    return quad(integrand, 0, rho, args=(alpha, r))[0]

alpha_0 = 1
r_0 = 1
rho = 5.0

vec_expint = np.vectorize(my_function)

res = opt.minimize(my_function, np.asarray([alpha_0, r_0]), method='CG', tol=1.e-2, args=(rho),options={'gtol': 0.01, 'maxiter': 5})
print(res)
```

Output:

```
     fun: 0.0018415003336983448
     jac: array([-0.00523077,  0.00762011])
 message: 'Optimization terminated successfully.'
    nfev: 12
     nit: 2
    njev: 3
  status: 0
 success: True
       x: array([ 2.06899361, -1.1785839 ])
```

Answer (score 1):

First, let me point out one thing that might be confusing you: you have a global (actually, module-level) variable named `rho` and a local variable named `rho` inside `my_function`. These are not the same. It might help clear things up to rename the global variable to `rho_0`, i.e. replace the last few lines of your code with this:

```
alpha_0 = 1
r_0 = 1
rho_0 = 5.0

vec_expint = np.vectorize(my_function)

res = opt.minimize(my_function(rho_0), np.asarray([alpha_0, r_0]), method='CG', tol=1.e-2, options={'gtol': 0.01, 'maxiter': 5})
print(res)
```

Now, the problem you are experiencing comes from writing `my_function(rho)` inside your call to `opt.minimize`. When you write `my_function(rho)`, it means you are *calling* `my_function` with one argument, and that argument is the value of `5.0` which you are storing under the name `rho_0`. But `my_function` requires *two* arguments: `parameters` and `rho`. You can't call it with one argument. That's why Python gives the error you're encountering.

In order to do what you want, you have to be aware that `opt.minimize` requires a *function* as its first argument. For example, you could call

```
opt.minimize(my_function, ...)
```

What you were giving it is the result of calling a function,

```
opt.minimize(my_function(...), ...)
```

which is not the same thing.

As you know, the function you pass to `opt.minimize` needs to have a signature like

```
def my_function(parameters, arg0, arg1, ...):
    ...
```

When you want to pass specific values to `arg0`, `arg1`, etc., you use the `args` argument of `opt.minimize`.

```
opt.minimize(my_function, parameters_0, args=(arg0_value, arg1_value, ...)
```

Inside `opt.minimize`, at each evaluation step it will choose values for the `parameters`, pack them up into a tuple, and pass that as the first argument to `my_function`, while it does the reverse with whatever you pass to `args`: it unpacks that tuple into individual arguments and passes them to `my_function` after the `parameters`.

Comment: I got it! Thank you for the profound explanation! it helped me a lot!